# Does restoring an Oracle backup of the whole database restore schema objects?

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, backup, rman

I used `RMAN` with,

```
RMAN>backup database archivelogs all;
```

After that I truncated a table.

I then tried to restore with,

```
RMAN>restore database;
RMAN>recover database;
RMAN>alter database open;
```

I connected with sqldeveloper, and the table is still empty.  I have tried many times.  I made sure there wer archive files with crosscheck backup.  It simply never restores the data to that table in the schema.  I know you cannot restore a single table, so I restored the whole database thinking it would put my data back.

There is one database, one backup, truncate, one restore (did this a lot).  I have tried `set until` for an incomplete backup, many things.  I don't need a point in time, however.  I was trying to get anything to work.

I received no errors.  Everything looked good.

(edit)

- All disk backup.
- Oracle Enterprise Linux 6.5.
- Oracle 11gR2, 11.2.0.3

(edit)

- I have not used logminer.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're issuing a "recover database" command, which will recover the database as far as possible.  If that includes the archivelogs/redo logs which contain your "truncate" command, then this will also be re-played and the table truncated again.

Try doing the restore on it's own, or recovering to a specific time using RECOVER UNTIL... then opening the DB read-only to see if it's in the state you expect.